# Using System.Text.JSON as serializer for .Net session middleware

Tags: .net, session, redis

How can I store the session data in Redis as JSON (via System.Text.JSON) instead of som binary format?

```cs
// Program.cs 
...
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
    {
        options.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
    }
);

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
});
...
```

This configuration works, but the data is stored in Redis in binary format. Is it possible to store iti

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        // Cấu hình thời gian timeout và cookie
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    })
    .AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
    {
        options.Configuration = "your_redis_connection_string"; 
        options.InstanceName = "YourAppInstance"; 
    });
```

AddDistributedRedisCache used for store session, data serialized to json by default.